# Counting lines of code in a Django project

Tags: python, django, bash

I use this shell script to count the lines of code in a Django project,

```
find . -name "*.py" -type f -exec grep . {} \; | wc -l
```

How can I modify this to not count the migration scripts? Essentially that means not count anything inside any subfolder by the name `migrations`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given you want to exclude all files in a directory named `migrations`, you can add a condition to the `find` command:

```
find . -name "*.py" -type f ! -path '*/migrations/*' -exec grep . {} \; | wc -l
```

Note that counting the number of lines is probably easier with [**`cloc`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc):

```
cloc --not-match-d=migrations .
```

This will then generate a summary like:

```
$ cloc --not-match-d='migrations' .
     102 text files.
      86 unique files.                              
      38 files ignored.

github.com/AlDanial/cloc v 1.74  T=0.88 s (97.3 files/s, 42411.8 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XML                              2             11             32          33299
Python                          63            619            273           2673
HTML                            18             35             49            304
JavaScript                       2              8              5            100
CSS                              1              5              6             81
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                            86            678            365          36457
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```